# Sending messages to channels - bot.send_message no longer works

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

A while back, I used to send messages to channels like this:

```
def broadcast(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(channel_id, text)
```

And I would reply to the user with:

```
def reply(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text(text)
```

Now, it seems that the arguments for `CommandHandlers` have changed from `(bot, update)` to `(update, context)`. As a result, I can still reply to the user with the `update` argument, something like this:

```
def reply(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(text)
```

But I can no longer send messages to a channel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From documentation](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0#what-exactly-is-callbackcontext), `bot` is available in `context`.

> So what information is stored on a CallbackContext? The parameters
>   marked with a star will only be set on specific updates.
>
> - bot
> - job_queue
> - update_queue
> - ...

So the function,

```
def broadcast(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(channel_id, text)
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
def broadcast(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(channel_id, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above `bot` is available in `context` so alternatively the function

```
def broadcast(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(channel_id, text)
```

can be rewritten as

```
def broadcast(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    bot.send_message(channel_id, text)
```