# Telegram Bot API Python - telegram.error.BadRequest: Chat not found

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want to create a bot to post my texts to a channel...
Can anyone help me with the code?

this is the code that I tried :

```
import telegram

token = "5002307835:AAGOu4f******************"
chat_id = "1382******"


bot = telegram.Bot(token)


def send_message(message):
    return bot.send_message(chat_id,message)


send_message("HI")
```

but i got this error : telegram.error.BadRequest: Chat not found

also i tried : `chat_id = "-1382******"` and `chat_id = -1382******` and `chat_id = 1382******`

Comment: which module are you using?

Comment: I'm using Telegram module.

Comment: Assuming you're using `python-telegram-bot` it seems you're using old formatting, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399278/sending-messages-to-channels-bot-send-message-no-longer-works)

Answer (score 1):

use it without `" "`

e.g.

```
import telegram

chat_id = 1382******
token = "TOKEN"
```

if not work, try it with `-` and no `""`, it will works!

e.g.

```
import telegram
    
chat_id = -1382******
 token = "TOKEN"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but the same error pops up...

Answer (score 0):

Channels ids usually starts with -100, so

```
chat_id = -1001382******
```

Put it as integer

You can also get the channel id sending a message in the channel as normal user and handling it with the bot. In message.chat.id you will see the correct id
Or just forward a channel message to the bot https://t.me/nguLikJSONbot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be administrator of a channel and then send message to it.
For send text, file or photo with caption to a specific user, the target user should be member of your bot and then change chat_id to user id in telegram.

```
import telegram

token = "5002307835:AAGOu4f******************"

# "@{0}".format("botfather") ==> @botfather
chat_id = "@{0}".format("your_channel_name")
# For sending message to a specific user
# chat_id = 18558...    

bot = telegram.Bot(token)


def send_message(message):
    return bot.send_message(chat_id, message)

your_msg = "Hello"
send_message(your_msg)
```